# Switching back to outlook appointment from a custom formregion

Tags: c#, outlook

In my appointment-creation window there's a button that changes the current view to a form region i created. Inside the form region I've got a button. When that button is clicked, I want to show the appointment creation view. What I've tried so far after searching stackoverflow was this:

```
        AppointmentItem = this.OutlookItem as Outlook.AppointmentItem;
        var t = AppointmentItem.Application.ActiveInspector();
        if (t != null)
        {
            t.SetCurrentFormPage("Appointment");

        }
```

This crashes, saying that there's no page named appointment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What form region type do you use? Is it an adjoining, replace or replace-all form region type?

Make sure that a string value you pass to the method is the correct one. To be sure try to handle the [PageChange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff869845.aspx) event of the Inspector class which is fired when the active form page changes, either programmatically or by user action, on an Inspector object. The name of the active page will be passed as a parameter to the handler.

Comment: The form region type is Separate. I've tried searching for the correct strings to pass into the pagechange, however I've come up empty handed.

Comment: Did you try to handle the PageChange event of the Inspector class? What values are passed to the event handler?

Comment: It works. I'm not running Outlook in English, which caused some problems when trying to access Appointment (I assumed that the page would be called appointment in the code no matter what language outlook was running in, I was wrong).